# How to compile RtMidi API properly on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, midi

I’m using C++ on visual studio 2019 and having issues trying to link my project to PortAudio. When I use the RtAudio header file in a project, I get the error message "MidiInDummy: This class provides no functionality." Most solutions I can find online say to add `__WINDOWS_MM__` to the pre-processor definitions and link to winmm.lib (as instructed on [https://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Egary/rtmidi/)) However, having done this, I am still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I get the error message "MidiInDummy: This class provides no functionality."*

This warns that no valid MIDI API was defined. The warning is issued from the constructor of the `MidiInDummy` class in `rtMidi.cpp`, which is just a placeholder without functional implementation.

> *add `__WIN_MM__` to the pre-processor definitions*

That is the wrong `#define` for the Windows build, which explains the `MidiInDummy` warning. The correct definition, listed on the reference page under [Compiling](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Egary/rtmidi/index.html#compiling) is:

```
#define __WINDOWS_MM__
```

Once `__WINDOWS_MM__` is defined, the sample `cMidiIn.dsp` project builds fine with VS 2019 after fixing a few remaining minor issues:

- `error D8016: '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible` - change project Properties / C/C++ / General / Debug Information from `/ZI` to `/Zi`;
- `warning D9035: option 'Gm' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release` - change project Properties / C/C++ / Code Generation / Enable Minimal Rebuild from `/Gm` to `/Gm-`;
- `warning C4138: '*/' found outside of comment` - add a space before `/*userData*/` in:

  ```
  void mycallback(double deltatime, std::vector< unsigned char >* message, void* /*userData*/)
  ```

Comment: Apologies, ``__WIN_MM__`` was a typo on my behalf, I have in fact used the correct preprocessor definition ``__WINDOWS_MM__``. I've edited the post to correct it. Am I meant to include the "#define" in the preprocessor definition, or does VS do that for me? Either way, it doesn't work

Comment: @ducksforever You must `#define __WINDOWS_MM__` before `#include "RtMidi.h"` or define it in the project Properties / C/C++ / Preprocessor / Definitions of the project, like the sample `cMidiIn.dsp` does. If you get an error about `MidiInDummy` that means you did not define it correctly, because `MidiInDummy` only gets compiled `#if !defined(__WINDOWS_MM__)`, as you can see in the `rtMidi.cpp` source file.

Comment: I had added the definition to the wrong solution in VS. As ever, there was a problem between keyboard and chair. Thank you for your time :)